# Printing a "Hello World" in bourne shell without directly using white space char

Tags: linux, sh

I'm currently trying to solve a tricky/silly challenge and i've come to a dead end.

The challenge is basically to form a one-liner /bin/sh compatible command line
which essentially outputs "Hello World" without directly typing White space or Tab characters in the command itself.

for example something like -

```
echo Hello World
```

would be invalid since we used white space twice in the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's valid, why not? Everything after `echo` will be displayed, including whitespaces.

Comment: cause that's the term of the challenge.

Comment: Oh I see.. you want to *make* it invalid..

Comment: i want something that does "echo Hello World" without using white space in the command prompt

Comment: you have whites in your command line.. :\

Comment: Consider asking your question here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code golfing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that IFS by default is set to space:

```
 # echo${IFS}a${IFS}b
 a b
```

Tested on Solaris 10 sh.

Answer (score 1):

Cheating a little, but it gives the correct effect (superficially) in `bash`:

```
PS1=hello$'\x20'world$'\n'"$PS1"
```

for example,

```
$ PS1=hello$'\x20'world$'\n'"$PS1"
hello world
$
```

The problem is that it will print `hello world` after every command in future :-)